# TestNG not grouping results from a single method

Tags: java, eclipse, testng, testng-eclipse

[image: Eclipse TestNG Results of running suite]

Refer the attached picture,
Class Name : T01_Files
Method Name : M01_Files_BiSync

My expectation is that all the 5 failures listed in the report should be grouped under method 'M01_Files_BiSync'. But it is not getting grouped. Please let me, know what I could be missing.

Comment: Could you open an issue on https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues ?

Comment: Issue created https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/293

Answer (score 1):

I think this is introduced by PR #172 for issue #167 .
I don't have a solution in mind for, be honest, I don't think this deserves a "fix".
please push me on the github [ticket](https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/293) if you have any suggestion.
thanks